how to to manually kill tween in Godot 4?
i'm trying to make a rpg-style dialogue system in godot 4 by using tween.
here is my code:
var isrun = false

func addText(next_text):
    isrun = true
    maintext.text = next_text #maintext is label node
    maintext.visible_ratio = 0
    var tween2 = create_tween()
    tween2.tween_property(maintext, "visible_ratio", 1, len(next_text) * readFast)

func _on_button_pressed():
    if isrun == false:
        addText("texttexttext")
    elif isrun == true:
        $addText.tween2.kill(self)
        isrun = false   

this is what i expected:
when i press button:

if it is the first time that i pressed the button: execute addText function

or if it is the second time that i pressed the button: kill tween2 in addtext funtion

excute addText function works well, but kill tween2 doesn't work
how can i solve this problem?

.kill() does not take any parameters.

Judging from the example code you provided the problem is one of scope. You create the tween2 variable in the addText function. Therefore it should be undefined/null in the _on_button_pressed function.
Add a "global" (in your script) variable that holds the tween and try creating the tween in your _ready function.

thank you so much. after i declare tween as global var, it works perfectly!

thanks for the help!
now i solved the problem!
here is modified code:
var isrun = false
var tween2

func addText(next_text):
    isrun = true
    maintext.text = next_text
    maintext.visible_ratio = 0
    tween2 = create_tween()
    tween2.tween_property(maintext, "visible_ratio", 1, len(next_text) * readFast)

func _on_button_pressed():
    if isrun == false:
        addText("texttexttext")
    elif isrun == true:
        tween2.kill()
        isrun = false


